# ontouch code on IOS is not the same as on Android touch and windows touch?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this code for that it can open `div` boxes and shadows on `div` boxes when you slide over it.

```
if (!("ontouch" in document.documentElement)) {
    document.documentElement.className += " no-touch";
}
$('html').on('touch touchend', function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('over');
});
```

But I noticed that on a samsung galaxy 5 it doesn't work as good as on an iphone.

When using an iphone it just works on sliding over it. BUT on an android on windows touch phone you really have to press it a little to have the same effect. Is there a way to fix this?

You can test it on my webste https://www.gester.nl if you have both phones.

Thanks for the answers in advance.

Greetings from Holland.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery takes care of most cross browser problems like this - you have it so use it.. Also, you might mean `ontouchstart` rather than `ontouch`.

```
if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)) {
    $(document.documentElement).addClass("no-touch");
}
$('html').on('touch touchend', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('over');         
});
```

Comment: I am asking because i don't know jQuery. SO there is not like a standard line that fixes that it will react the same on android phones?

Comment: @GesterFromHolland u mean like the one I gave in my answer??

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it still doesn't open my div block when i touch and slide over it. With IOS it opens when i touch over it. With android i really need to press it sort of to open that div box that you see on my homepage at https://www.gester.nl